# SurfaceView flickering when scrolling

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask, surfaceview

I have a scrollview and nested several custom `SurfaceView` within. As I scroll, the `SurfaceView` background begins to flicker black. I have researched this for at least a day now and am unable to find a solution. I have tried to implement the solution of this thread: http://android-coding.blogspot.ca/2012/01/flickering-problems-due-to-double.html but found no success.

With my SurfaceView, I am trying to draw text and a downloaded image of an emoji. Initially, I used a custom view but was blocked after attempting to download a bitmap in the UI thread and recieved a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So I tried to use an `AsyncTask` for the entire onDraw() portion of the view. However, the View remained blank, and I was unable to update it after the `AsyncTask` finished. I tried to call invalidate() on the view after the `AsyncTask` finished but it resulted in an endless loop of onDraw(). Then I created a boolean variable to stop this loop and render the view only once, but it ended the same way I started: a blank view.

Now I am attempting to use a `SurfaceView` because I read

> One of the purposes of this class is to provide a surface in which a secondary thread can render into the screen

and thought I should use it because I am using a seperate thread to download a bitmap.

Now that I implemented a `SurfaceView`, it does not work the way I want it to as it flickers black as I scroll. I have recorded it here: https://youtu.be/o5j9s4XF65E

Pastebin of faulty code here: https://pastebin.com/g61aSNM2

The questions I am asking:

- Should I be using a `SurfaceView` for this purpose? If not, then what would be the proper way to implement this?
- Should I be using a `Thread` instead of `AsyncTask` to download a bitmap from url?
- Why is SurfaceView flickering and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I spent some time rethinking the structure of my View and realized I should not be using `SurfaceView`.

I made my CustomView, `TextMessage`, extend `ImageView` and during `onDraw()` I called my custom `AsyncTask<TextMessage, Void, Bitmap>` which simply creates a Bitmap of what the View should be. After `AsyncTask` finishes, during the `onPostExecute()` method I called `setImageBitmap(myBitmap)` on the `TextMessage` which I first passed as the parameter.

This is so simple I complete overthought my problem, I never should have used `SurfaceView` in the first place.